# My prefix command doesn't work ( discord bot) discord.py

Tags: python, pycharm, discord, bots, discord.py

Hey I'm using pycharm to create a discord bot and i got this issue: the prefix command doesn't work no matter how many times i run my code and i checked it I don't think i made any mistakes please help me
Her's my code :

```
import random
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='&')
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=2):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
client.run('token')
```

Comment: what's the error/how are you triggering it? I don't see a command named `prefix`, which command are you referring to?

Comment: Does your bot have the `manage_messages` permission? You should have enabled it in the developer portal when you were generating the link to invite it. You can check its role to see the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it a name: `@client.command(name="clear")`

Comment: shouldn't make a difference, if no name is supplied then the library will use the function's name as the command's name

Answer (score 0):

To do it you need to have Import discord

```
import discord
```

Comment: They appear to already have imported from `discord` using `from discord.ext import commands`,  so that doesn't look like the problem. However, the question doesn't specify what the problem or error actually is.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have your token stored as a variable.
And I suggest, though not required, you add line breaks instead of it being one large block.

And,
1. Use a print("This should be working") for debugging purposes.
2. Make sure your bot has permissions, make sure when you were adding your bot you clicked the checkbox on `Manage Messages` or `Administrator`. If you can't remember if you did, no worries, you can add the bot again with the correct permissions via your bots OAuth2 page settings which can be found [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Comment: wrong, you do not need to pass ctx as an arg to the `command` decorator, indeed this will instead throw a NameError as `ctx` is not defined.

Comment: I'm sorry I was thinking of a name there, it should be passed in the defining of the command which the author did. My apologies.